# PyCharm does not display output at all

Tags: python, pycharm

I worked with PyCharm for a few weeks and it did not have any problems. Then suddenly it stopped showing output for any program. I honestly don't understand what's wrong.

I tried updating Python and PyCharm but without any results.

My PyCharm Screen:

[image]

Comment: Not related to your problem, but it's best to avoid whitespace in a Python filename (like "Class Variables.py"). It would cause problems if you tried to import that file into another. Often we use underscore instead to provide visual spacing, for example "Class_Variables.py".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not running the "SuperYT" program - you are running the "Class Variables.py" which probably has no visible output. You have to choose the right file from the window next to the run arrow: [image: window]